# how to load image from url and share that image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share image using `UIActivityViewController`.
This is my code.

```
- (IBAction)shareBUttonClick:(id)sender
{
   for(int i=0; i<[self.imagesDataArray count];i++)
  {
     [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesDataArray objectAtIndex:i]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];  
     NSArray *postItems=@[imageView];
    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:postItems applicationActivities:nil];

 //if iPhone
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
//if iPad
else 
    {
    // Change Rect to position Popover
    UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
 }
}
```

but, its giving me `null(UIActivityViewController open in real device but sharing not there)`

Please help me.

Comment: are you check the image is added or not

Comment: are you allocating the memory of your imageview

Comment: i'm new in ios so, you give me idea what should i do?
if i am static added image then its working file but my images come from url.

Comment: try this `NSArray *postItems=@[imageView];` in this place use `NSArray *postItems=@[imageView.image];`

Comment: Warning: Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x164d9600>  on <ImagesDetailScreen: 0x18439be0> which is already presenting (null)
this error

Comment: for this error see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934881/warning-when-presenting-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: it won't help...

Comment: is this possible to attach the project i will check

Comment: No sorry.......

Comment: First save image to document directory and then use the path to share.

Comment: okay,thanks for help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sdwebimage downloader async , then call upload function:

```
 [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] options:SDWebImageDownloaderUseNSURLCache progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {

                        if (image && finished) {
    // now upload   
                              [self sendImageToShare:(UIImage *)image];
                        }
                    }]; 


    /*********************/


    - (void)sendImageToShare:(UIImage *)yourImage {
        if (yourImage) {
        NSMutableArray *activityItems= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:yourImage, nil];
        UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to prepare all URLs and prefetch images

```
    NSMutableArray * urls = [NSMutableArray   arrayWithCapacity:things.count];
    for(int i=0; i<[self.imagesDataArray count];i++) {
        [urls addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:   self.imagesDataArray[i]]];
    }
    [SDWebImagePrefetcher sharedImagePrefetcher]
```

with callback, then you can put downloaded images into share controller

Comment: code is working but i need, directly put images into share controller.